# function bounded by an exponential has a bounded derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

here's the question. I want to be sure of that. Let $v:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ a positive function satisfying
$$\forall t \ge 0,\qquad v(t)\le kv(0) e^{-c t}$$
for some positive constants $c$ and $k$. Can I conclude that
$$\dot{v}(t) \le -c v(t)$$ ?

Comment: No. You can have a $v(t)$ oscillating below the curve $kv(0)e^{-ct}$ with arbitrary derivative.

Comment: yes I see! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. Look at something like $v(t) = e^{-t}\sin(g(t) t)$. Then $v'(t) = e^{-t}(\sin(g(t)t) + g(t)\sin(g(t)t)$. If you choose $g(t)$ so that it grows fast enough, your original function will be bounded from above by exponential decay, but you can make the derivative grow as fast as you like.

Edit: This reply doesn't look at the positivity condition, but this should be fixable by replacing $\sin(g(t) t)$ with something like $2 + sin(g(t) t)$

Comment: Your function doesn't necessarily satisfy non-negativity or positivity.

Comment: True, I missed that part in the question, my bad. But it should be fixable by replacing the $\sin(g(t)t)$ with $2 + \sin(g(t))t)$ and scaling appropriately.

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 2):

No. I will show a non-negative function which does the job (it's easy enough to turn it into a positive one). Take $v(x)=e^{-x}\cos^2(e^x)$. Clearly we have $v(x)\leq v(0)e^{-x}$. The derivative, which is $-e^x\sin(2e^x)$, is not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Take $v(t) = e^{-t} (1+\sin(e^x) )$

$v'(t) = \cos(e^t)-e^{-t} (1+\sin(e^t))$

and v'(t) doesn't converge to 0